# Check Input Data Type In Console Application C#

Tags: c#, console-application

How to check input data type in c# Console application..

```
Class A
{

 object o=Console.ReadLine();
 //logic here to check data type and print
//e.g type of Integer, Decimal, String etc

}
```

if i give input of `23` then it'll print `'Integer'`

if i give input of `23.9` then it'll print `'Decimal'`

if i give input of `"abcd"` then it'll print `'String'`

What i'm trying to do is..
Something like

```
Class A
{
Type t=Typeof(Console.ReadLine().GetType);
Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" service. It's for helping people with specific, practical programming problems. Please make some effort, and provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, with a detailed explanation of what specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) will always return a `System.String`

Comment: yes, i know and i'm not expecting to write my code by anyone, i'll do it myself.i just wanted to know the way or  an idea which'll help me writing this code.
**you can tell me that i didn't explain well the question, i'm not good at(as far as i know).

Comment: _"i just wanted to know the way or an idea which'll help me writing this code"_ -- that's far too broad a question. There are many ways to approach the problem as stated, and you haven't even provided an unambiguous specification. For example, you say that `"23"` should print `'String'`, but what should `twenty-three` print?

Comment: yes, that's the point that I've given you the bad example, i'm changing it..Thanks @PeterDuniho

Comment: The edited post isn't any different from the previous in terms of clarity. For example, if the user enters `abcd`, what should the output be? And more to the point, **what have you tried**?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `if (o.GetType() == typeof(int))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any magic, though you can search the package managers/github.  You're going to have to parse the input string.  [.Net Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4QKHvE)

```
string o = Console.ReadLine();

string finalType = "String";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)){

  // Check integer before Decimal
  int tryInt;
  decimal tryDec;
  if (Int32.TryParse(o, out tryInt)){
    finalType = "Integer";
  }
  else if (Decimal.TryParse(o, out tryDec)){
    finalType = "Decimal";
  }    

}

Console.WriteLine(finalType);
```

Comment: yes, I've written this way, and i think you missed something, cause we need to check Decimal before checking it as Integer.

Comment: I changed to else if in an edit.  If it is an integer with no decimal, it will report as integer.  If it is a decimal, the else if block will hit and report as decimal.  Otherwise it reports as a string.

Answer (score 1):

for future readers ... I had similar task and I've come up with the following solution:
* Anything coming as an input from the console is considered a string type.In C# you need to parse your input into a specific type where possible.

```
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

// `typeToCheck`.TryParse(input, out _) - Will return True if parsing is possible.            

                if (Int32.TryParse(input, out _))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is integer type");
                }
                else if (double.TryParse(input, out _))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is floating point type");
                }
                else if (bool.TryParse(input, out _))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is boolean type");
                }
                else if (char.TryParse(input, out _))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is character type");
                }
                else // since you cannot parse to string ... if the previous statements came up false -> IT's STRING Type.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is string type");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the input string is enclosed in double quotes. If so, print String.

Then use long.TryParse to check if you can parse to long. If so, print Integer.

Then use decimal.TryParse to see if you can parse it as decimal. If so, print Decimal.

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the incoming data.  Depending on how many types you need to deal with, you can go a couple different routes:

- Many simple data types have a static method called `TryParse()`.  You can use this method to see if the input string can be parsed as each type.  This is only a good solution if you are dealing with a very limited number of types.
- You can use Parsing Expression Grammars ("PEG") or similar approach, which allows you to define a formal grammar for parsing arbitrary text.  The advantage to this approach is that you can also support complex structures (i.e. lists of values, nested values, etc.).  This approach is extremely flexible and expressive, but it also has a much bigger learning curve.
- You can use Regular Expressions, which provide a similar capability as PEGs, though usually in a more limited context.  You should be able to easily find regular expressions for common simple data types (numbers, booleans, strings, etc.).